# Wicket - clearInput() after form submission not working

Tags: forms, wicket, submission

I want to clear form components (textfields etc) and it model. On submit method, after persisting the model correctly, I call clearInput(), but nothing happends to model and fields still filled.

Am I forgetting something about **clearInput()** method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `clearInput()` you need to set an empty model object and to rerender the form.

Please show us your code if these suggestions do not help.

Comment: Yes it worked, adding `getModel().setObject(new ModelClass());` to _onSubmit()_ it clears the form as wanted and still working properly. The strange is _clearInput()_ is not necessary.. just the line above... do you know why?

Comment: `clearInput()` is used to get rid of invalid input, that wasn't transferred into your models. If your form submits without validation errors, there's no input to clear.